# How to fix Google Cloud Messaging Registration error:PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I encountered a strange problem - I am using GCM with my application for a month but now its has stopped working on my nexus 4 (running Lollipop 5.0.1, stock Android).Everytime I try to get a registration id from Google server it returns me `Error :PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR` .I know this error is for devices that runs android version 2.2 and below as they do not support GCM but why is it happening for my device although it was working few days back.

```
<permission
    android:name="diver.volo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="diver.volo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="diver.volo.components.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="diver.volo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you try downloading an app that uses GCM to see if it'll work on your device?

Comment: @Andy Yes I have lots of apps which uses GCM and works fine on my phone